# getting the name of the application

Tags: ios, iphone, cfbundledisplayname

I have a lite and a full version and want them to work with different configuration Files.

Now I need to query, within the application, if the application name has "lite" in it and load the coresponding config-file
I havent found how to do it. Any Idea ?
Or is there generally a better approach for that ?

Thanks in advance
Heiko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processName]
```

This returns process name, which is usually your application's name.

Answer (score 5):

If you want what was put into the Info.plist file, use:

```
NSString * displayName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You application has a main() in main.m (if you used a template).  It gets passed the command-line arguments and argv[0] should be the full path of the application, which you can parse.  You'll have to save it in a global variable.

You could also check the launchOptions in the appDelegate to see if it's there too.

Comment: ahhh damn. I should have remembered this from a long ago c lesson :-)
thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Swift:

```
if let appName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String {
    print("App Name - \(appName)")
}
```

Also try this, if you've set Display Name

```
if let displayName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleDisplayName"] as? String {
    print("App Display Name - \(displayName)")
}
```

Useful trick:

```
// Print bundle info dictionary to get complete details about app
print("Bundle.main.infoDictionary - \(Bundle.main.infoDictionary)")
```